# Azure APIM oAuth workflow - refresh token is missing

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management, azure-oauth

I enabled oAuth in Azure API management. Then using ClientId, Client Secret, Scope, Access Token URL & Grant Type, I was able to get the access token. How can I get the refresh token from the API ?

[image]

Comment: what is the scope for this request ? you need to add the `offline_access` scope to get the refressh token

Comment: @Thomas: I do not follow your question. Can you please share more information about scope? I did defined the `Application ID URI` to define `custom scopes to restrict access to data and functionality protected by the API.`. Are you suggesting when I send `scope` instead of sending `Application ID URI`, I should set scope as `Offline_access`? Does it mean I need to make two calls, one to get `access token` & another one to get `refresh token`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get refresh token from the API, you need to add **`offline_access`** permission in the scope.

Please note that, **Client credentials flow** works with permissions of **Application** type only. So, you won't get refresh token using this flow as **`offline_access`** permission is of **Delegated** type.

Instead, you can make use of **Authorization Code flow** as Grant Type.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

In my Azure AD application, I added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

To get refresh token, change the grant type to **Authorization Code** and include **`offline_access`** in the scope like below:

[image]

When you selected `Get New Access Token`, one new window will open where you have to **login** with your credentials as below:

[image]

After successful authentication, you will get both ***access token*** and ***refresh token*** like below:

[image]
[image]

You **don't have to** make two separate calls like one to get **`access token`** and another one to get **`refresh token`**.

Instead, you can directly add **`offline_access`** in the **scope** along with custom Api scope.